# How to get a value from a hash into the multidimensional array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm getting a multidimensional array with a bunch of key-value hashes inside of it, just like that:

```
[{"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}, {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}, {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}, {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}]
```

What I need, is to get all the `key1` values from this array and just couldn't figure how to perform it. Any suggestion would help, thank you.

Comment: fwiw, that array is not multi-dimensional. It is a plain array of hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  arr = [{"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}, 
    {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}, 
    {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]},
    {"key1"=>"value", "key2"=>[value, value]}]

  key1s = arr.map{|h|h["key1"]}
```